# Submit form after data validation

Tags: forms, reactjs, validation, redux, jsx

I created the form with validation using React and Redux. 
The conditions for the validations:

- the data shall be validated at the time of input
- the data shall be validated again before submission
- all data all fields are mandatory and the data is valid

When user started to input data I check the data and send them at the time of input to the store using dispatch. 
When user click the button "submit" first I check if the data has value and send them state to the store.

*Question:*

If at the time of submit all data has valid value does need I send the data to the store again?

My action *./actions/index.js* :

```
export const changeValue = (field, value, isValid) => ({
type: "CHANGE_VALUE",
  value, isValid, field
})
```

My reducer *./reducers/form.js* :

```
const form = (state={
 firstName: {isValid: true, value: ''},
 mail: { isValid: true, value: ''}
 }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'CHANGE_VALUE':
      state[action.field].isValid = action.isValid
      state[action.field].value = action.value
      const user = Object.assign({}, state)
      return user
    default:
      return state
  }
}
export default form
```

My containers for the form *./containers/Form.js* ::

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { changeValue } from '../actions'

const hasOnlyLetters = value => value.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/)
const re  = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i
const hasEmail = value => value.match(re)

const Form = ({ dispatch, inputs }) => {

  // Check the data at the time of the data input
  const changeHandler = (isValid, field, e) => {
    const { value } = e.target
    if (isValid(value)){
      dispatch(changeValue(field, value, true))
    } else {
      dispatch(changeValue(field, value, false))
    }
  }

  // Check the data before submission
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (!inputs.firstName.value) {
      dispatch(changeValue('firstName', inputs.firstName.value, false))
    }
    if (!inputs.mail.value) {
      dispatch(changeValue('mail', inputs.lastName.value, false))
    }
    if(!inputs.firstName.isValid || !inputs.mail.isValid) {
      return alert('error')
    } else {
     // Send the data to the store again?
      return alert('success')
    }  
  }


  const error = (field, type) => {
    if (!field.value && !field.isValid) {
      return <span>Field is required</span>
    } else if (field.value && !field.isValid && type === "text") {
      return <span>Should contain only letters</span>
    } else if (field.value && !field.isValid && type === "mail") {
      return <span>Value should be a valid email</span>
    } else{
      null
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
        <label>First name:</label>
        <input type="text" value={inputs.firstName.value} onChange={changeHandler.bind(null, hasOnlyLetters, 'firstName')}/>
        { error(inputs.firstName, "text") }
        </div>
         <div>
        <label>Email:</label>
        <input type="mail" value={inputs.mail.value} onChange={changeHandler.bind(null, hasEmail, 'mail')}/>
        { error(inputs.mail, "mail") }
        </div>
        <button type="submit">
          Add Todo
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}


function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { inputs: state.form }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Form)
```

Comment: Why do you think you should "send the data to the store again"? I guess you may send/post it to a backend (which will eventually update the store).

Comment: I couldn't figure out what you ask. You can send data as many times as you want and just merge it. If you want to prevent double submissions just disable the submit button once clicked and data validated.

Comment: Just as a tip: I'd recommend to write the state update in the dispatcher like this: `return  {...state, [action.field]: {value: action.value, isValid: action.isValid}}`. This way you don't need `user` and the state remains untouched (immutable).

Comment: And i didn't get why you return user. You assign user to the state not state to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to first set the values in state and perform a validation. Once they are validated in the component, you can set the correct values in the store.

```
`export default class Form extends React.Component{

     constructor(props){
         super(props);
         this.state={
             name:'';
             age:''
         }
     }

     handleSubmit=()=>{
         if(this.state.name===''){
             perform validation
         }
         else if(this.state.name===''){

         }//other validation(s)
         else 
         {
             //set data in store only when the fields are correct..
         }
     }

     render(){
         return (<div>
             <input type="text" onChange={(event)=> 
                 {this.setState({name:event.target.value})}} />
             <input type="number" onChange={(event)=> 
                 {this.setState({age:event.target.value})}} />
             <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
        </div>)
     }
 }`
```

This will help you have only the validated data in the store.